# Flexbox: Auto width to Header, auto to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox div, that is justified start and aligned start. Inside that div are two divs, the first contains an h1, the second contains a paragraph.

I am trying to set up a flexbox configuration so that div 1 is always the width of the header (h1) and the rest of the space is taken up by the second div with the paragraph.

Here's my set up:

```
<div class="flex flex-justify-start flex-align-start">
    <div class="title">
        <h1 id="landingHeader">Headline</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <p>Duis porttitor, neque in egestas pretium, nisl velit facilisis turpis, nec scelerisque nibh est faucibus purus. Nam ullamcorper facilisis turpis, sagittis varius turpis luctus in. Mauris pulvinar erat eget nisi tincidunt venenatis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNQPPo

Comment: @Justin Breiland ...not quite. the headline div (div1) had to expand width-wise to fit the headline (h1)

Comment: @Murphy1976 I don't think I am quite understanding your question.  maybe add a mockup/wireframe of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Justin Breiland ... ok instead of what your CodePen is doing, where if you type in "Headline Headline" into the H1 and the second word flows to below... I'm looking to have the width of the div the H1 is in to expand out to the right, causing the div containing the Paragraph to shrink.

Comment: @Murphy1976 updated my pen, that should be what you are looking for.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out...
It's a combination of setting the div.title to have a flex-shrink property of 0, and the div.text to have a flex-grow property of 1 and a flex-shrink property of 1